# Cocoapods install "You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory"

Tags: xcode, unix, installation, rubygems, sudo

I'm trying to uninstall Ruby/gem so I can reinstall it. Just updating it has it hit a bunch of errors. It won't let me uninstall it at all because it says I do not have the write permissions for the stated directory.

The confusing part is I tried to find the directory in finder and it literally does not exist. There is a Ruby directory in the Library itself but no Frameworks/Ruby.framework

How do I fix this issue? I'm reticent about disabling the security of my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Create this directory and in terminal write:

```bash
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
```

Then retry to uninstall.